# How do I copy a file from the "Temporary Internet Files" directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, temporary-files

I am trying to save an image file (`png`) called `home` located in the below directory as a `.gif` file:
`C:/Users/Raj/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files`

When I right click the file and click properties, the cache name is shown as `home[1].png`, so I tried the following code to save it to a `.gif`:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('C:/Users/Raj/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files/home[1].png')
img.save('output.gif')
```

But I get an error saying `no such directory or file` so I am a bit confused where I am going wrong with this.

Comment: What is confusing? By the time you went to read it, the file had been removed.

Comment: The file is still located within the directory whilst the code is running and is only removed once IE is closed therefore, I am not sure that this is the case.

Comment: Oh. You're right-clicking the file *in the Temporary Internet Files* folder and looking at its properties there. I'll write you an answer.

Comment: Did some further digging. If you go in there with the command line, you'll quickly see that the files you are seeking don't actually appear in there. The fact that they appear in there is an illusion created by Explorer. I don't know of any way to translate it into a real path.

Comment: That's interesting, I will search around for this and see if I can find any further information. Thanks for your help with this, its greatly appreciated.